# GetGUIThreadInfo() returns TRUE but GUITHREADINFO contains only zeroes

Tags: c, windows, winapi, focus

I use Windows 7 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.
This is my code below (I start notepad.exe and want to find focused sub-window handle:

```
STARTUPINFO         si  = { 0 };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi  = { 0 };

memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));

si.cb = sizeof(si);

BOOL bResult = CreateProcess("c:\\windows\\syswow64\\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
HWND hWnd = FindWindow("Notepad", NULL);

DWORD dwTID;

dwTID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, NULL);
GUITHREADINFO info = { sizeof(info) };

AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), dwTID, TRUE);
GetGUIThreadInfo(dwTID, &info);
AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), dwTID, FALSE);
```

`FindWindow()` returns correct hWnd; and `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` returns correct TID of window thread (have checked it in Spy++). Both `AttachThreadInput()` and `GetGUIThreadInfo()` return TRUE. But `info` contains only zeroes (except `cbSize` member which contains size of structure). If I use `GetFocus()` I still receive NULL.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Code looks fine, works fine on Win8.1.  AttachThreadInput() is not necessary, GetFocus() is supposed to return NULL.  You'll have to look for some obscure environmental problem.  Try another machine, disable anti-malware, etc.

Comment: I have disabled anti-malware protection on my PC (Windows 7 Professional, anti-malware is Avira), still does not work. Tested it on another computer (W7 Home Basic), it works! What's the problem? I need universal solution.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to get another process' child window with focus?

Comment: You need GetForegroundWindow() to know what window the user is interacting with.

Comment: Got it. If I do step-by-step debugging in MSVC, hwndFocus returns NULL. If I start EXE so that Notepad window is foreground - I get hwndFocus. But  I want to get handle of focused child window even if window is not in foreground.

Comment: `hwndFocus` is the window that *currently* has the **keyboard focus**, if there is one. If the requested thread does not have a window in the foreground, it does NOT have keyboard focus. That is why `hwndFocus` is NULL. It is a side effect of your debugging, the debugger has the focus.

Comment: OK, but focus must be saved before switching windows, isn't it? When I restore window, focus is at that window as it was before minimizing. Is there a way to obtain it?

Comment: Got it. Focus is not saved in some windows, on other it saves and restores. The default is to save focus or not?

Comment: You are using the wrong tool altogether. Automating a GUI is best done with [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable I am making remote access tool; not to access whole desktop but to access one application. But I need to allow user to continue his work on computer while network admin works with window which can be not a foreground window at the same time.

Comment: As I said: You are looking for [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). Unless you wish to solve an unsolvable problem.